# In iTunes Connect, why a distribution certificate already exists?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes

I haven't created a distribution certificate.
But in `iOS Provisioning Portal > Certificates > Distribution`, a distribution certificate already exists. 
Why?
Don't I need to create distribution certificate manually?

Comment: Do you have co-worker to work with you? Did they create it?

Comment: No, i don't have co-worker. I'm developing alone.

Comment: I suspect it is created by Xcode when you first refresh certificate in Xcode organizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is already exist and **invalid** then `Revoke` it and again create you distribution certificate. Its not created automatically you have to make it. May be someOne else did this  task or you did and then forgot it. 
So just renew it.

Comment: Just renew it if it is invalid. A valid distribution certificate does not require renewal.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 thanks. it's valid certificate. And I didn't created because I don't know how to create it.